# Dropwizard reading request JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson, jersey, dropwizard

I'm sending a very simple POST request with a JSON body of just "id":"string". I get the following in response when I send my post:

```
{
    "id": "robert"
}
```

-

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Unable to process JSON"
}
```

-

```
@Path("/myapp/user")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UserHandler {

    @POST
    public void doPost(Entity e) {
        System.out.println(e.id);
    }

    public class Entity {
        @JsonProperty String id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was missing the @JsonProperty identifier... this fixed it:

```
public class Entity {
    @JsonProperty("id") String id;
}
```